# How to perform click event with single button to select different DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am having the div structure as follows

```
<div id="header">HI</div>
<div id="content">HI Good morning </div>
<div id="footer">Last </div>
```

Initially all the divs will be visible. I am having a button at the top of the page. On the first click cursor has to come in First `<div id="header">HI</div>` on the second click cursor should move to  `<div id="content">HI Good morning </div>` and on third click cursor would move to  `<div id="footer">Last </div>` and Viceversa.

Please anyone help on this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include some attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: what do you mean with "...cursor has to come...". There is no cursor in divs unless you're in edit mode.

Comment: I believe for a div there is no focus event unless its an input field stiil based on wat u mentioned i have done a fiddle..check whether something like this u where looking for...http://jsbin.com/eXUPUzE/2/edit

Comment: Cursor i mentioned there is starting letter of the DIV.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think div supports .focus(), however you can create your own focus.

---

You can simply use the index value the select each div, no matter how much of these 'messages' you got. I'm using the [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector for this. Now everytime you click a button, it will select the first index(first index is 0 with the eq() selector). When you click the button again, the selector should select the second index( index 1 ). 

For this you can simply create a div that increase everytime there is clicked on the button.

```
var clickIndex = 0;

$('button').click(function()
{


    $('div:eq(' + clickIndex + ')');

    clickIndex = clickIndex + 1;
})
```

Now you want to scroll the page at the divs height. You can do this with a animation or a hash redirection. 

**Animation**

So what you want to do is animate the scrollbar of your browser to the top position of your div. To get top position, you can use [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

```
$('html,body').animate({
scrollTop: $('div:eq(' + clickIndex + ')').offset().top
},
'slow');
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tCTPp/)**

Now you may want to reset the clickIndex variable when the last message has been selected.

**Hash redirection**

As you may know the 'hash' stands for the id that will be selected. Basically when the #id is placed after the url, that specific id will be selected.

 Normally you could this with an anchor hash href. But with a button you can use `window.location.hash` for this. This will extends the url with your input.

You will do the same as the animation, but this time you also need the id of each element.

Simply get the id of the selected element and store it in a variable:

```
var id = $('div:eq(' + clickIndex + ')').attr('id');
```

Now extend the url with this id and the hash:

```
window.location.hash = '#' + id;
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tCTPp/5/)**

*Note: this doesn't functional in jsFiddle, test it in your own code!*

---

I hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Hi nkmol thanks for your solution its works...Is there any possibilities to have Hash redirection with animation.. Thanks

Comment: Well, i don't think so. You would have to 'catch' the redirected hash and also prevent it from scrolling, thus disabling the default hash redirection. If it's possible, it will become a mess and probably not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try an anchor tag around each div with an onclick attribute for focus on next id.

Sorry for being vague it's a long time since I've done it but search focus on w3c schools and that will make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

First you can't focus on div you can focus on input type and for that method is:

```
var tab = 0;
  $("#buttonID").click(function(){
    if(tab == 0){
      $("#firstID").focus();       //first click
      tab=1;
    }
    else if(tab == 1){
      $("#secondID").focus();      //second click
      tab=2;
    }
    else if(tab == 2){
      $("#thirdID").focus();      //third click
      tab=0;
    }
 });
```

Comment: Hi Anup thanks for your reply. i have used your code but its not focusing the particular div part its work when i give the alert msg after each condition but not redirecting to particular div starting point.. Please help

Comment: you need to use input tag with in your div read my answer carefully. You can't focus on div brother or you can use one hidden input field, just provide your full need with jsfiddle example otherwise you need to add and remove class with your clicks for that no need to use focus function. http://api.jquery.com/focus/